# Airflow jobs stuck in scheduled state

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

Airflow version - 2.4.3

I wanted to run 40 parallel tasks in a dag, thus have set the parameter of max_active_runs = 40 for the dag.
Although airflow is running 40 parallel task, but only 5 jobs get into the running state.

Rest of the jobs are stuck at scheduled state.

NOTE - These jobs are the ones that creates a new kubernetes  pod via Kubernetes Pod operator.

I am running sequentialExecutor, and don't want to change into LocalExecutor in production, as this will take a lot of time. Please suggest a way to run all 40 jobs together.

Below is the screenshot for reference.

Let me know if any other information is required.

[image]

Comment: sequentialExecutor is not recommended in production please check https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/sequential.html